# How to detect if the logic PCB can successfully communicate with the power PCB

Tags: power-electronics, electricity

In most devices (As washers, refrigerators etc.) you find a logical board (The one the user interacts with and mostly has the buttons and a digital or an LCD screens etc.) and you find the power board that that has the transformer, triac, relay etc.

The power board powers the logic board with a DC current, and the logic board sends different commands, I believe via electrical pulses, either via multiple pins or like in Morse code, which being received by a Microprocessor in the electrical board, which takes the appropriate action, like starting the motor etc.

**My question is**

In the pictures below, you find both boards connected via 10 pins, I believe 2 of them to provide DC power to the logic board from the power board, and I believe the other 8 pins is to deliver the command messages to the power board from the logic board.

DMM has 2 terminals, positive and negative, **How should I connect them to these wires (Pins) to detect if the logic board indeed sending command messages to the power board?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all. A DMM is meant to measure constant signals (either DC or AC), not changing information signals.

What you'd need is a logic analyzer, and a bit of knowledge on the basics of serial interfaces like **UART**, **SPI** and **I²C**. Your question betrays that you're still missing too many basics – but that can be changed.

> Because when I say sending a command or an electric pulse, in my mind the logic board will send electrons to the power board.

No, that's not how electricity works. A current flows, but the net amount of electrons always stays the same (and is irrelevant). What the transmitting end does is impose a voltage or a current on a wire.

> Which means in my mind that these 8 Pins are paths for electrons from the logic to the power board. So to detect the electrical pulse on my DMM, I should connect the negative terminal to one of these pins, but where do I connect the positive terminal.

This betrays that you really need to think about what voltage is. The fact that there's electrons involved doesn't mean any voltage has to be negative.

Honestly, feels like you've skipped the part where you learn the basics of electricity (current, voltage, resistance, linear networks, Kirchhoff's law…), and try to skip to digital circuits.

That won't work. Take a step back, get a book or any other good introduction to the very basics of electronics.

(to answer the question: can't be said, probably you should connect your negative probe to device ground, and your positive to the data line, but these lines might be differential, and most definitely clocked themselves, so again, no chance measuring anything useful with a DMM.)

Comment: I don't want to change the information signal. And though I'm pretty new to electronics, but I don't see what I said wrong or different from what you just said, I didn't assume the number of electrons is changed. Clearly I misrepresented my thoughts, sorry for the inconvenience and thank you so much for the advice and assistance, really appreciated.

Comment: Especially with unknown signal voltages and types, one should initially start with a scope rather than a logic analyzer at least to identify what sort of signalling is being used.  Most modern digital scopes also have some limited logic analyzer functionality on the analog channels.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy I said nothing about you changing the information signal.

Comment: "Not at all. A DMM is meant to measure constant signals (either DC or AC), not changing information signals." And neither did I ;) Have a wonderful day, and hopefully I'll get my hand on the source of the problem soon. Which I started to doubt it's not the logic nor the power boards. Again, thank you.

Comment: THe signals are changing themselves.

Comment: Hmmmm Now I see what you meant. Clearly I'm the one who's lately having a problem in the communication with others not my logic-power PCBs LOL